# Creating innerHTML within a Div & also getAttribute from within that same div

Tags: javascript, getelementsbyclassname, selectors-api, getattribute

Im trying to figure out a way I can grab and attribute from a div and create a link within that same div including the attribute in the src

What I have so far just grabs the first Attribute so all links are the same.

Im very much a JS beginner so forgive me if the answer is obvious

```js
var srpVin = document.querySelectorAll('span[data-cg-vin]')[0].getAttribute("data-cg-vin");

 var srpVsaBtn = document.getElementsByClassName('carBannerWrapper');
for (var i = 0; i < srpVsaBtn.length; i++) {
    srpVsaBtn[i].innerHTML += '<a href="https://myurl.com/?vin='+srpVin+'&dealer_id=28987" target=_deal>Click here - '+srpVin+'</a>';
}
```

```html
<div class="carBannerWrapper"><div><span data-cg-vin="1FMCU9G66MUA11123" data-cg-price="34399"></span></div></div>
<div class="carBannerWrapper"><div><span data-cg-vin="MAJ3S2GE7LC386456" data-cg-price="34399"></span></div></div>
<div class="carBannerWrapper"><div><span data-cg-vin="11FMCU9H67LUC59789" data-cg-price="34399"></span></div></div>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get all the spans with `querySelectorAll`. This returns a `NodeList` object. These objects have a `forEach` function to loop over the items inside of the object.

In the loop, each `<span>` is exposed. This means you can access properties of these elements and manipulate them. Since you're using data attributes I'd advice to use the [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) property, which holds the values of each data attribute.

Then instead of using `innerHTML`, use [`document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) to create a new `<a>` tag. This creates an anchor tag as an object. Here we can manually set the `href` property of the anchor based on the value of the dataset.

Then the [`append()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append) method on the span to add the anchor as a child of the current span in the loop.

Note: `_deal` is not a valid value for the `target` attribute. See the list of possible values: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-target

```js
// Collect all spans with the data-cg-vin attribute.
const srpVin = document.querySelectorAll('span[data-cg-vin]');

// Loop over each span.
srpVin.forEach(span => {
  // Get the data-cg-vin attribute value of the current span.
  const cgVin = span.dataset.cgVin;

  // Create a new <a> tag..
  const anchor = document.createElement('a');

  // ..and set the href, target and textContent based on the data attribute value. 
  anchor.href = `?vin=${cgVin}&dealer_id=28987`;
  anchor.target = '_blank';
  anchor.textContent = `Click here - ${cgVin}`;

  // Add the anchor to the span.
  span.append(anchor);
});
```

```html
<div class="carBannerWrapper"><div><span data-cg-vin="1FMCU9G66MUA11123" data-cg-price="34399"></span></div></div>
<div class="carBannerWrapper"><div><span data-cg-vin="MAJ3S2GE7LC386456" data-cg-price="34399"></span></div></div>
<div class="carBannerWrapper"><div><span data-cg-vin="11FMCU9H67LUC59789" data-cg-price="34399"></span></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are looking for forEach (to iterate over a nodelist):

```
var srpVin = document.querySelectorAll('span[data-cg-vin]').forEach(function(elem,idx) {
  elem.getAttribute("data-cg-vin");

});
)
```

Comment: Swap `idx` and `elem` around, and replace `this` with `elem`. The first argument of the callback function is the item, not the index

Answer (score 0):

Use forEach to iterate through each item.

```js
var srpVsaBtn = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.carBannerWrapper'));

srpVsaBtn.forEach(button => {
  const link = button.querySelector('span').dataset.cgVin;
  button.innerHTML = '<a href="https://myurl.com/?vin='+link+'&dealer_id=28987" target=_deal>Click here - '+link+'</a>';
})
```

```html
<div class="carBannerWrapper"><div><span data-cg-vin="1FMCU9G66MUA11123" data-cg-price="34399"></span></div></div>
<div class="carBannerWrapper"><div><span data-cg-vin="MAJ3S2GE7LC386456" data-cg-price="34399"></span></div></div>
<div class="carBannerWrapper"><div><span data-cg-vin="11FMCU9H67LUC59789" data-cg-price="34399"></span></div></div>
```